# How to integrate 3rd deivative?

Tags: calculus

$∫ xd^3x$

How to integrate this?

Do we need definite integrals for it?

I have nothing else to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int d^3x$ is a somewhat common way of writing a volume integral. So $\int xd^3x$ is also known as $$\iiint x\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

Comment: $$\iiint x\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ means I will integrate x first with respect to x then y and then z or I will have to do it simultaneously?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel One at a time. Are you not familiar with volume integrals?

Comment: OK! Its called volume integral. Rest I can search on internet.

Comment: Where did y and z came from?

Comment: When you write $d^3x$, the $x$ stands in for all spatial coordinates (this is different form the $x$ that _doesn't_ have a $d$ in front of it; that one is only the $x$-coordinate). When you write "dx\,dy\,dz$, the three spatial coordinates all get their own separate, standard names. I admit that it is a small mess of shorthand notations, which can be confusing at first, and difficult to get into.